# How to test a method whose sole purpose is to calculate its sleep duration and sleep it

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

How am I supposed to test a method like this? (without having to wait the sleep duration)

```
                  #    A method in the Time class    #
"""Sleeps until the minute count on the digital clock is divisible by 5."""
@staticmethod
def sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5():
    seconds_left = Time.calculateSecondsLeft()
    minutes_left = Time.calculateMinutesLeft()
    sleep(minutes_left * 60 + seconds_left)
```

Here is how I would do it if I didn't care about having to wait the duration

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from Time import Time   # This is my time class
from datetime import datetime

class TestTime(TestCase):

    def test_sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5(self):

        Time.sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5()  # Sleep until the minutes is divisble by 5

        assert (datetime.now().time().minute % 5) == 0  # Check the minutes is divisible by 5
```

Comment: You create some way to "simulate" time.

Comment: Or, alternatively, make your function is "pure" so that doesn't need to interact with the real world. Let the caller handle that. Same reason why printing directly to stdout is usually a lame idea.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That is a very good point, the reason why I don't do that is because I need to "sleep the duration until the minute is divisible by 5" a lot of times, so it makes sense to create a method for it so to avoid `sleep(Time.getTimeUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5())` and have `Time.sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5()` instead (for the sake of readability) -- imagine having the former a lot of places vs the latter.

Comment: Could you show the code you would use to test this, assuming you don't care about your test running slowly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to mock `time.sleep` method. Then it will execute immediately.

E.g.

`Time.py`:

```py
from time import sleep


class Time:
    @staticmethod
    def sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5():
        seconds_left = Time.calculateSecondsLeft()
        minutes_left = Time.calculateMinutesLeft()
        sleep(minutes_left * 60 + seconds_left)

    @staticmethod
    def calculateMinutesLeft():
        return 1

    @staticmethod
    def calculateSecondsLeft():
        return 40
```

`test_Time.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from Time import Time
from datetime import datetime


class TestTime(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('Time.sleep', return_value=None)
    def test_sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5(self, mock_sleep):
        Time.sleepUntilMinuteDivisibleBy5()
        mock_sleep.assert_called_with(100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/59680752/Time.py           10      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/59680752/test_Time.py      10      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        20      0   100%
```